# Universal link redirection does not redirect but html link does

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

Anyone know why this :

`window.location.href = "myapp://"`

or

`window.location.replace("myapp://")`

does not redirect to the app from a browser but this :

`<a href="myapp://">myapp</a>`

Does ?

Comment: It's a security feature of your browser to avoid XSS attacks.

Custom URI schemes are typically used for specific system-level actions, such as launching native applications or accessing device functionalities. So it can have big security implications if an injected JavaScript code could trigger it. 

When you use an anchor tag `<a>`, the browser recognizes it as a valid link and allows the navigation, once it has the user's intention to navigate to it.

Comment: Ok, so this work as intended. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: There’s no warning in safari leaving the user alone with the feature not working. I had to search like mad to understand